LDAP and elasticsearch
I want to apply LDAP configuration for user authentication on Kibana.
I configured LDAP, restarted the Elasticsearch service, but I'm unable to authenticate.
I launched a tcpdump towards the LDAP server's IP address to monitor the packets generated during authentication.
I noticed that it manages to retrieve the user, but then, in the authentication part, it uses the group instead of the username for authentication.
Why is that? Do I need to modify something in my configuration?

You need to provide a lot more details on how you configured your LDAP realm. It's impossible for us to give you good advice about a configuration that you haven't shown to us.
